Is there any good way to export my WIF(wallet import format) private keys into one and the same wallet? And can you trace public keys from privatekeys
I have a lot of token's from aavev1-v2-v3 to xml, xrp, zcash and on and on. All have different privatekeys. Is there a good way to get all the assets with privatekeys into one wallet? Or must I use different wallets for different tokens and chains?
And is there someway to get the public key from the private key? So you can track all assets?
There's of course gonna be some trouble with the assets from CEX:es, any ideas how to solve that also?

Public key can be directly derived from a private key. But unsure about the other stuff.
